# Execute PHP script if a JavaScript condition is true

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I am running a javascript timer that can be activated by a start button and whenever the count is more than 30 minutes I want it to run an email script so that the email can be send to the intended recipient with the user having to actually send the email manually.Here is the php email code`

```
<?php
 $to = "sa01@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Vehicle Monitoring system ";

 $message = "<b>Vehicle not logged out</b>";

 $header = "From:vehicle001@gmail.com \r\n";
 $header .= "Cc:sa001@gmail.com \r\n";
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

 $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

 if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
 }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
 }
?>`
```

Here is my javascript code`

```
var status =0;
var time = 0;

function start() {
status = 1;
document.getElementById("startBtn").disabled = true;
timer();
}

function stop(numberPlate) {
status = 0;
var time = document.getElementById('timerLabel').innerHTML;
var car_no = numberPlate;
var stx = {no : time};
console.log(stx);
window.localStorage.setItem(car_no, time);  
}

function reset() {
status = 0;
time = 0;
document.getElementById("startBtn").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}

function timer() {
if (status == 1) {
setTimeout(function() {
time++;
var min = Math.floor(time/100/60);
var sec = Math.floor(time/100);
var mSec = time % 100;

if(min < 10) {
min = "0" + min;
}

if (sec >= 60) {
sec = sec % 60;
}

if (sec < 10) {
sec = "0" + sec;

 }

document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec + ":" 
+ mSec;
timer();

}, 10);
}
}

function output() {
document.getElementById('timerResult').innerHTML = 
document.getElementById('timerLabel').innerHTML;

if(timer>=1){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var result;
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       console.log("Success");
       result = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "sendmail.php", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

`
This is how the table looks like.[image: Vehicle registration table]How do I do that?

Comment: Why you don't use Ajax or Websockets ?

Comment: Hi Mamdouh,can you walk me through.I am fairly a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `XMLHttpRequest()`  to have the PHP file be requested.

In this example, `file.php` is accessed if `condition` is true. The result is stored in the `result` variable.

```
if(condition){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var result;
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           console.log("Success");
           result = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "file.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```